# QML device deployment

Tags: android, c++, deployment, qml

I have set the project to run QML with C++ having slots communication. Now I am stumbled with the message:

```
void QDeclarativeView::continueExecute()): 
    file:///data/data/org.qtproject.example.input/files/Input.qml: File not found
```

I searched around and checked a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243199/qml-loading-file-not-found), thus I followed that suggestion, changing my project file as follows:

```
QT += qml quick sensors xml
QT += declarative
SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
OTHER_FILES += \
    Input.qml
HEADERS += \
    Input.h
RESOURCES += \
    Input.qrc

# Required for deployment (?) :
QML_FILES.source = qml
QML_FILES.target = .
DEPLOYMENTFOLDERS += QML_FILES
# Required for deployment too (?) :
include(qmlapplicationviewer/qmlapplicationviewer.pri)
qtcAddDeployment()
```

While adding this hack to the project file seems to work for Symbian and Harmattan, for Android the last two lines doesn't fix the problem, as the compiler gives the messages:

```
./input/qmlapplicationviewer/qmlapplicationviewer.pri:-1: error: No such file or directory
./input.pro:22: 'qtcAddDeployment' is not a recognized test function.
```

Even for Qt5 should we get worried about the [target](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/19465), even if when we defined the project we already set it for Android device?

So, could someone have any suggestion on how to get the QML deployed to Android device? Maybe some equivalent hack that will do the same magic that worked for Symbian but also could work for Android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to downgrade your Android target from API 19 to 17. Apparently the API 19 is not working properly with [Qt 5 for Android](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-qt/kmpW7MHJV2U) yet.

Using qtcAddDeployment and qmlapplicationviewer.pri might also solve your issue. But before going into that direction, you should have a close look in the article from Qt Blog on [Android Deployment in Qt 5.2](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2013/10/09/android-deployment-in-qt-5-2).